# How to share code between two classes having same parent?

Tags: c++, oop, mfc, polymorphism

Although I am using MFC, I believe this is primarily a C++ question.

I have `CResizingDialog` derived from `CDialog` which is the base class for all my dialogs in the application. It gives them the ability to automatically (you guessed it) resize according to target screen size. CResizingDialog achieves this by overrides CDialog's several virtual functions including `OnSize()`, `OnInitDialog()`, `OnPaint()`. So far well and good.

Now I am adding a property sheet/page which also needs the same resizing functionality however I can't use CResizingDialog as base class for my property page. This means I will need a new base class say CResizingPage derived from `CPropertyPage` which will contain same functionality as CResizingDialog.

However the code that resizes the dialogs and its controls is exactly the same. Is there a way I can reuse the CResizingDialog somehow? I have never used multiple inheritance, will that help here?

Comment: If you want to reuse the resizing code you will have to factor out the resizing code from `CResizingDialog` and reuse that in your dialog/property page implementations. Multiple inheritance isn't going to help here, mostly due to MFC's plumbing macros.

Comment: Look into the decorator design pattern.

Comment: I'm not into MFC so excuse me if this is only C++ only.  C++ supports mutliple inheritance.  I have a system I'm using: Imagine class A, class B : public A and class C : public A.  If B is resizeable and C is focusable, you can create a derived class D : public B, public C which inherits both from B and C.  Why not inherit resizeable?

Comment: @Nick thanks, I was wondering if any design pattern might help here and I will follow up on your suggestion.

Comment: Do you need to inherit interface or only the implementation? E.g. do you have some public methods in CResizingDialog that are used outside the hierarchy? If not, you may be fine by using delegation (e.g. introducing a class member that provides the necessary logic).

Comment: @Chemistpp Both `CResizingDialog` and `CPropertyPage` inherit from `CWnd` and provide their own virtual overrides. Inheriting from both requires virtual inheritance. Things basically go downhill from there.

Comment: @Nick I tried implementing decorator pattern but in mfc world it is a lot of pain and may not be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I have 2 suggestions how to solve this, you'll have to decide which is easier/nicer for your situation.

If possible you can move the resizing code into a standalone function with the appropriate parameters that you can call from your 2 virtual functions.

The other way is to make the base class a template. Something like this:

```
template< typename Base >
CResizingBase
    : public Base
{
    // override the appropriate functions here
};

class CResizingDialog
    : public CResizingBase< CDialog >
{
};

class CResizingPage
    : public CResizingBase< CPropertyPage >
{
};
```

Comment: Seems promising but one trick thing is that I have CDialog >> CResizingDialog >> CMyDialog. But where will this fit for a property page? CDialog >> CPropertypPage >> ?? >> CMyPage?

Comment: I've never used MFC so I'm not familiar with the class structure. But wouldn't CDialog >> CPropertyPage >> CResizingPage >> CMyPage work?

Comment: That would be the only logical way although I was also thinking CDialog >> CResizingDialog but than CPropertyPage is a library class I can't change its base class. Seems like worth a try. I actually have to do the same thing for CPropertySheet as well which is derived from CWnd.

Comment: This is a neat idea but I think it will not work. The `CResizingBase`will have to initialize either `CDialog` or `CPropertyPage` whichever is it derived from. Now both of these have different constructors and I think this is a deal breaker. It has to pass the right stuff to base class in member initialization list which wouldn't be possible in this case.

Comment: You can make the constructor of `CResizingBase` a perfect forwarder. It takes in variadic template arguments and forwards them to the base class. I haven't used variadic templates that much so I may get this a bit wrong but I think the code should look something like this.
`template< typename Base >`
`class CResizingBase`
    `: public Base`
`{`
`public:`
    `template< typename T... >`
    `CResizingBase( T args... )`
        `: Base( std::forward< T >( args )... )`
    `{}`
`};`

Comment: Variadic templates are [not supported in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx). The Visual Studio 2013 Preview seems to have them.